# Как правильно посчитать азимут для поворота карты?

Tags: c++, c, математика, qt5, qml

У меня есть карта, которую мне необходимо повернуть.
Делаю поворот я с помощью свойства `bearing` у `Map`.
Мне не совсем понятно как правильно делать поворот относительно текущего положения карты, то есть азимут я считаю следующим разом

```
constexpr double constrain(double angle) {
    angle = std::fmod(angle, 360.);
    return angle < 0. ? angle + 360. : angle;
}

void GlobalMapProperty::setBearingByXY(const int &x, const int &y)
{
    const qreal bearing = Angular::constrain(std::atan2(y, x) * 180. / M_PI);

    setBearing(bearing);
}
```

Где функция setBearingByXY это свойство объекта, который задаётся в контекст. В функцию передаются координаты позиции мыши.

```
onPositionChanged: {
     if (pressedButtons == Qt.MidButton) {
                    console.log(mouseX, mouseY)
                    globalMapProperty.setBearingByXY(mouse.x, mouse.y)
                    _mouseArea.cursorShape = Qt.ClosedHandCursor
     }
}
```

Сейчас код отрабатывается и карта успешно поворачивается, но почему-то не совсем корректно. А именно если я нахожусь в Fullscreen режиме, то при зажатой СКМ по оси ординат или абцисс (если полностью проходить), то карта поворачивается на половину. Я почему-то думаю, что у меня где-то ошибка с вычислением азимута, то есть я не совсем верно его высчитываю. Может быть мне стоит его считать относительно центра экрана как-то?

Update: Как правильно передать координаты мыши, чтобы карта поворачивалась корректно. То есть при нахождении в верхней части экрана при зажатой СКМ, опускаясь вниз (нижняя часть экрана) азимут поворота был от 0 до 360, то есть полный поворот. Это первый уточняющий вопрос.
Второй вопрос, если я повернул карту, и начну поворот заново, то поворот карты начинается заного, со стартовой позиции, предполагаю что это координата Qt.point(0, 0) для мапы.

Comment: А за что минус то дали?

Comment: Предположу что минус дали за то что вообще неясно чего вы хотите. Опишите в вопросе что с картой до клика мышкой, как должна выглядеть карта после клика мышкой.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, по-моему всё предельно ясно. Я написал, что поворот карты не совсем корректное. На пальцах, есть ось ординаты, ставим курсор мыши в верх экрана, проводим курсор при зажатой СКМ вниз экрана до упора, азимут высчитывается от 0 до 180 (приблизительно), а должен быть полный поворот экрана. Плюс может быть я не правильно передаю координаты мыши в саму функцию.

Comment: Мне, читателю вопроса, неясно что не работает. Вы вычисляете угол правильно, а карта поворачивается неправильно? Вы неправильно вычисляете угол? Какой должен быть угол для различных положений мыши? Пожалуйста, делайте правки прямо в вопросе, не в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Азимут считался неверно! Нужно было во-первых: задать относительно чего производить вращение, во вторых начальную и финальные точки, где начальная точка - это точка нажатия мыши сигнал `onPressed`, а финальная точка - это точка текущего положения курсора `onPositionChanged`.

```
void GlobalMapProperty::setBearingByXY(const QPointF &start // точка старта,
                                       const QPointF &end // точка последнего положения мыши,
                                       const QPointF &origin // позиция, относительно которой производится вращение)
{
    qreal l;
    qreal x1 = start.x() - origin.x();
    qreal y1 = start.y() - origin.y();

    l = x1 * x1 + y1 * y1;

    if (!qFuzzyIsNull(l)) {
        x1 /= l;
        y1 /= l;
    }

    qreal x2 = end.x() - origin.x();
    qreal y2 = end.y() - origin.y();

    l = x2 * x2 + y2 * y2;

    if (!qFuzzyIsNull(l)) {
        x2 /= l;
        y2 /= l;
    }

    const qreal a1 = std::atan2(y1, x1);
    const qreal a2 = std::atan2(y2, x2);
    const qreal bearing = a2 - a1;

    setBearing(-bearing * 180. / M_PI);
}
```